# Move to First Screen in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I my application, I display 3 to 4 Screen using following code.

```
 main.pushScreen(screen);
```

Now I want to display first screen.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now again to display first screen,
You need to create an object of first screen once again 
and display using following code.

```
 main.pushscreen(firstscreen).
```

Hope it will help you.